# What are (potential) disadvantages of using meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have just watched the [meteor.js screencast](http://meteor.com/screencast) and I'm quite blown away by how easy building a web application with it seems, in terms of live updates and database synchronisation. However, I am not sure of how well it would scale once it's live.

What problems (potential or real) could I have if I decide to build and deploy a web application written on meteor.js?

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote? Isn't this question useful at all to anyone else?

Comment: @animuson I just saw it's been put on hold... would this question be suitable for community wiki? The two original answers have been useful, but I can see it attracting less useful ones.

Comment: It is not opinion-based, it is rather experience based. It would really help the developers to make a decision in their early phase of analysis. This type of questions must not be closed.

Comment: It's really frustrating to see Stack closing or deleting so many questions that are useful but contain opinions... It is very difficult for any question to strictly avoid opinion unless there is only a single method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, I would advice you have a play about with meteor and make the judgement yourself. It really depends on what you wish to develop

Certain constraints I have found are

- Meteor comes bundled with only mongodb. Other database support are planned for later releases
- No model/object form binding (in road map)
- Package system is not npm (although Meteor is built on node) and is closed to community. All meteor packages are developed by meteor themselves

Regarding performance, I found this [article](http://projectricochet.com/blog/meteor-js-performance#.UZM-jsBwaAg) helpful

Here is another [link](https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae) to meteors roadmap

From my experience, I would say the advantages I have found outweigh any disadvantages at the moment

Comment: Regarding the package system - you can still use node packages in meteor with ease, as well as the meteor package system and meteorite

Comment: Cheers rickyduck I will have a look into meteorite

Comment: With Meteor development moving fast and this answer being over a year old, though it was worth mentioning [Atmosphere.js](https://atmospherejs.com/) for Meteor packages (which anyone can develop and make available to the community).

Answer (score 6):

Having built client projects in meteor there is 2 things I immediately found hindering about the system:

1) No native support for MSSQL / MySQL or in fact any other DB than MongoDB (which jamin mentioned). That said, it sort of makes sense as to why this is the case, as a NoSQL solution with an easy to use JS api makes sense over a clunk RDMB database. However there is a plugin called Meteor SQL which supports MySQL at the moment https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql

2) No native support for windows - Meteor is only released on linux & OSX meaning us windows users are out of the loop. There is an unofficial windows build on http://win.meteor.com but it's stuck at 0.5.9.

I probably wouldn't recommend building full sites out of Meteor yet as well due to it's various instabilities - https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues however in a controlled environment it's perfect.

Also bear in mind Meteor have achieved an $11m funding grant - http://venturebeat.com/2012/07/25/meteor-funding/ meaning it will continue to improve and grow.

Comment: Just an update, http://win.meteor.com has had a changing of the guard, and last I checked, is up to date with 0.6.3.1

There's Stephen Darnell's native solution, with an MSI installer.  And there are 2 Vagrant-based solutions (running Meteor in a Linux VM).

Comment: as of JUne 11, 2014 drorm/meteor-sql hasn't seen any update in the last year. abandoned?

Comment: Update - Windows officially supported as of version 1.1

Answer (score 0):

A huge problem for Application development are missing things like validation or translation.
You have todo everything on your own an include and use many external sources.
NPM support is not optimal, for backend usage ok, but in frontend a hack.